# populate missing values for multiple columns with multiple values

Tags: python, pandas

I have gone through the posts that are similar to filling out the multiple columns for pandas in one go, however it appears that my problem here is a little different, in the sense that I need to be able to populate a missing column value with a specific column value and be able to do that for multiple columns in one go.

Eg: I can use the commands as below individually to fill the NA's

```
result1_copy['BASE_B'] = np.where(pd.isnull(result1_copy['BASE_B']), result1_copy['BASE_S'], result1_copy['BASE_B'])

result1_copy['QWE_B'] = np.where(pd.isnull(result1_copy['QWE_B']), result1_copy['QWE_S'], result1_copy['QWE_B'])
```

However, if I were to try populating it one go, it does not work:

```
result1_copy['BASE_B','QWE_B'] = result1_copy['BASE_B', 'QWE_B'].fillna(result1_copy['BASE_S','QWE_S'])
```

Do we know why ?
Please note I have only used 2 columns here for ease of purpose, however I have 10s of columns to impute. And they are either object, float or datetime.
Is datatypes the issue here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add `[]` for filtered DataFrame and for align columns add `rename`:

```
d = {'BASE_S':'BASE_B', 'QWE_S':'QWE_B'}
result1_copy[['BASE_B','QWE_B']] = result1_copy[['BASE_B', 'QWE_B']]
                                     .fillna(result1_copy[['BASE_S','QWE_S']]
                                     .rename(columns=d))
```

More dynamic solution:

```
L = ['BASE_','QWE_']
orig = ['{}B'.format(x) for x in L]
new =  ['{}S'.format(x) for x in L]

d = dict(zip(new, orig))
result1_copy[orig] = (result1_copy[orig].fillna(result1_copy[new]
                                        .rename(columns=d)))
```

Another solution if match columns with `B` and `S`:

```
for x in ['BASE_','QWE_']:
    result1_copy[x + 'B'] = result1_copy[x + 'B'].fillna(result1_copy[x + 'S'])
```

**Sample**:

```
result1_copy = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'BASE_B':[np.nan,5,4,5,5,np.nan],
                   'QWE_B':[np.nan,8,9,4,2,np.nan],
                   'BASE_S':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'QWE_S':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})


print (result1_copy)
   A  BASE_B  BASE_S  F  QWE_B  QWE_S
0  a     NaN       1  a    NaN      5
1  b     5.0       3  a    8.0      3
2  c     4.0       5  a    9.0      6
3  d     5.0       7  b    4.0      9
4  e     5.0       1  b    2.0      2
5  f     NaN       0  b    NaN      4

d = {'BASE_S':'BASE_B', 'QWE_S':'QWE_B'}
result1_copy[['BASE_B','QWE_B']] = (result1_copy[['BASE_B', 'QWE_B']]
                                      .fillna(result1_copy[['BASE_S','QWE_S']]
                                      .rename(columns=d)))
print (result1_copy) 
   A  BASE_B  BASE_S  F  QWE_B  QWE_S
0  a     1.0       1  a    5.0      5
1  b     5.0       3  a    8.0      3
2  c     4.0       5  a    9.0      6
3  d     5.0       7  b    4.0      9
4  e     5.0       1  b    2.0      2
5  f     0.0       0  b    4.0      4
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, however am a little confused over the use of rename method in this case ? Do we need it ?

Comment: @asimo - try omit it and no change. :) Problem is need same columns names for both dataframes in `fillna`

Comment: This is nice and tidy :)
for x in ['BASE_','QWE_']:
    result1_copy[x + 'B'] = result1_copy[x + 'B'].fillna(result1_copy[x + 'S'])